# How to count unique results from multiple MySQL queries using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have what might be a simple question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I am trying to write a query that counts the number of unique results per query and stores both the values and the number of times it was a query result to a different database.

Here's an example of what I am basically trying to do...

Say I have a table 'color'

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |    color   |   letter   |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | blue       |      a     |
|          2 | blue       |      b     |
|          3 | red        |      a     |
|          4 | red        |      b     |
|          5 | green      |      a     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

I have a query that will run multiple times using this table
to find the corresponding letter and color:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM colors WHERE letter = '$someletter'");
$query1 = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$color = $row['color'];
};
```

For each query I am writing the $id and $color variables to a seperate log file.

For example, using the above query, $someletter = "a". (call this query #1)
The results would be:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |    color   |   letter   |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | blue       |      a     |
|          3 | red        |      a     |
|          5 | green      |      a     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Blue, red, and green would have one result each.

If the query was run with $someletter = "b" (call this query #2)
The result set would be:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |    color   |   letter   |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          2 | blue       |      b     |
|          4 | red        |      b     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Blue and red would each get one result.

So the total number of results for both queries #1 and #2:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|     id     |    color   | totalresult|
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 | blue       |      2     |
|          3 | red        |      2     |
|          5 | green      |      1     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Basically, I want to figure out a way to get a count of all the unique results for X number of queries. Because this query will be run multiple times with different variables, I would like to store the results in a database that could have a column for color and a column for total results as I have shown above. Also, I am just using the table 'color' as an example and the actual number of unique entries would be in the hundreds, so the query would have to work for that.

I was thinking of some form of COUNT or GROUP but I cant seem to connect the dots.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'SELECT color, COUNT(letter) totalresult FROM colors GROUP BY color';
```

That should give you the colors and the number of times it appears (per color). I've left out the `id` column, because you can't map a row to a single id so that information is useless.

**Update**

In order to store the search results you could create two tables. The first (search_query) only needs to contain an id and a varchar column to hold the query. You could add a timestamp also to find out when people use the search option.

The second table (search_results) contains one result per row. It consists of a foreign key to the first table, and the result. Instead of a complete result you also could log the id of the result row. (So if someone searches for the letter b you only would need to log color ids 2 and 4. That means you need two rows in the search_results table.)

If the search results could come from more than one table, you would need to add the table name to the search results table too. I would just use a varchar column for that.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to figure out the query to create the table with the total results column. I want to find out how to compile the unique results queries 1 and 2 into a database. Once I have that database I know how to extract the counts, I just cant make the table to begin with.

Comment: Can't you just create another table called QueryResults and for each time a query is run, populate that table with the rows. It would also help if you added a time-stamp column so you can later know when the query was run that produced the result.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to use is `mysql_num_rows($query1);` this returns the number of rows in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select color, count(id) from color group by color
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need 2 database accesses - one to retrieve the current total, and one to update it with the new total.